# Writing a function such that it can be applied to a grid

Tags: matlab

I would like to rewrite the following function such that it can be applied to a grid:

```
function [ PNE ] = generatevalues( a1, a2, b1, b2 )
function [F]=FOC(p)
F=[0 0];
F(1)=-(1+exp(-p(2)))*(p(1)-a1)+1+exp(-p(1))+(1-b1)*exp(-p(2));
F(2)=-(1+exp(-p(1)))*(p(2)-a2)+1+exp(-p(2))+(1-b2)*exp(-p(1));
end
P0=[0.1 0.1];
PNE=fsolve(@FOC,P0);
end
```

When I apply the function to a grid such as

```
x1gv = 0:0.1:0.1;
x2gv = 0:0.1:0.1;
x3gv = 0:0.1:0.1;
x4gv = 0:0.1:0.1;
[X1,X2,X3,X4] = ndgrid(x1gv, x2gv, x3gv, x4gv);
```

the following message appears:

```
    generatevalues([X1,X2,X3,X4])

Error using generatevalues/FOC (line 4)
Not enough input arguments.

Error in fsolve (line 241)
            fuser = feval(funfcn{3},x,varargin{:});

Error in generatevalues (line 8)
PNE=fsolve(@FOC,P0);

Caused by:
    Failure in initial user-supplied objective function evaluation. FSOLVE cannot continue.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the error is that the syntax you are using to call `generatevalues` is wrong.  By running `generatevalues([X1,X2,X3,X4])`, you are calling with a single input argument (i.e. `a1 = [X1,X2,X3,X4]`). *Remove the square brackets* to specify four input arguments, otherwise you are simply doing horizontal concatenation of `X1`, `X2`, `X3` and `X4`.

Once you get the correct syntax:

```
generatevalues(X1,X2,X3,X4)
```

You will have trouble with `FOC` since you no longer have just one system of equations.  If you are are trying to solve *several systems* of equations, you may need to call `fsolve` several times in a loop or with `arrayfun`. For example,

```
function [ PNE ] = generatevalues( a1, a2, b1, b2 )
function [F]=FOC(p,ii)
F=[0 0];
F(1)=-(1+exp(-p(2)))*(p(1)-a1(ii))+1+exp(-p(1))+(1-b1(ii))*exp(-p(2));
F(2)=-(1+exp(-p(1)))*(p(2)-a2(ii))+1+exp(-p(2))+(1-b2(ii))*exp(-p(1));
end
P0=[0.1 0.1];
PNEc = arrayfun(@(ii)fsolve(@FOC,P0,[],ii),1:numel(a1),'uni',0);
PNE = vertcat(PNEc{:});
end
```

I rarely use `fsolve` so I can't say if there is a way to do solve multiple systems without a loop (if that is what you want to do).

Comment: Yes, I am trying to solve several systems of equations, one for each point in the grid, by using fsolve without a loop. My objective is to modify 'generatevalues' such that it returns a grid of values in the same way as for example 'sin' does when one writes 'sin([X1,X2,X3,X4])'. At each point of the grid 'sin([X1,X2,X3,X4])' is obtained by applying 'sin' to the value of '[X1,X2,X3,X4]' at that point. Similarly, I would like 'generatevalues' to act pointwise.

Comment: Well, `sin` only takes one input argument, while `generatevalues` takes 4.  Hence the error when using square brackets this way.  Then to solve each system for all the values in the input arrays, you'd need to call `fsolve` in a loop (or with `arrayfun`) to solve each system.

Comment: Sorry, `sin` was not the right analogy. An example of a function that acts pointwise on a grid is `F=@(A1,A2,B1,B2)A1.*B1+A2.*B2`. Here `F(X1,X2,X3,X4)` gives a grid.